# how to check the parameter from get request

Tags: node.js, api, rest

I'm struggling building my restful API. I would appreciate anyone helping me with this
From get request like this: user/:UserId/cart/:cartId. How can I check cartId? I can only check the UserId by these code:
var user_check=user.find(c=>c.find === parseInt(req.params.userId));
THank you!

Comment: share the _actual_ code that builds your route and does this 'checking'. There's typos in what you typed here, so it's going to be difficult to know what's your actual problem and what are typos.

Comment: Cart ID should be accessible as `req.params.cardId`, try `console.log(req.params)` to see whats working in your params